# How to get row navigation in editable table in JDeveloper 12c?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am not able to get `row navigation` on arrow key in editable table?

I have to use `JDeveloper 12c(12.1.2.0)` version.

Actually I have done in `JDeveloper 11g` that work fine because `row navigation` is default functionality in `JDeveloper 11g`.

But this functionality not in `JDeveloper 12c`.

So please any body tell me how  to get this functionality in `JDeveloper 12c`.

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

- You can press `ESCAPE` to go out of edit-mode and navigate using the arrow keys. Press ENTER to go back in edit mode.
- You can navigate an editable table by using the `ENTER`, `SHIFT-ENTER`, `TAB` and `SHIFT-TAB` keys.